# Change HTML preview in WinEdt 9

Tags: winedt

I use WinEdt 9 on WIndows 10. How can I change the default HTML previewer in WinEdt 9? Currently, it is Chrome. I would also like to associate Shift+Ctrl+H to open the preview while editing an HTML file.

I looked at Options-> Options Interface -> Menus and.. -> Main Menu

There is an item

ITEM="TeXHTML_Preview"
CAPTION="HTML Pre&view"
IMAGE="IExplorer"
MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\HTML\Preview.edt');"
SHORTCUT="24648::Shift+Ctrl+H"
REQ_FILTER="%P%N.html"

but currently, it is not doing anything for Shift+Ctrl+H

F8 when pressed while editing HTML opens it in Chrome.